# differentiate $y=\ln (e^x (\frac{x-1}{x+1})^\frac{3}{2})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> differentiate $$y=\ln \left(e^x \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

I had tried to solve it following way :

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{e^x \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^\frac{3}{2}} . \left(e^x \frac{x-1}{x+1}+e^x . \frac{3}{2} \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^\frac{3}{2} . \frac{x+1-x+1}{[x+1]^2}\right)$$

Is it correct? I am sure that if it is correct than, my further work is correct also. My book had solved the problem another way. They just designed $y$ at first then, differentiate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you proceed as follows?

$$y = \ln(e^x) + \ln \left( \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^\frac{3}{2} \right)$$
$$= x \ln(e) + \frac{3}{2} \ln \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$$
$$= x + \frac{3}{2} \big( \ln(x-1) - \ln(x+1) \big)$$

using the rules of logarithms.

This is now much easier to differentiate.

---

You should have:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{e^x \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^\frac{3}{2}} . \left(e^x (\frac{x-1}{x+1})^{\color{red}{3/2}}+e^x . \frac{3}{2} \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\color{red}{1/2}} . \frac{x+1-x+1}{[x+1]^2}\right)$$

Comment: Yes! But, I had solved that way at first. That's why I was thinking if that's correct...

Comment: Doing it this way reduces the chance of you making mistakes: by a lot.

Comment: Could you check my work if it is correct?

Comment: @Istiak I've updated my answer. What a way to practice all the differentiation rules!

Comment: Nice answer @TobyMak (+1)